# Як перекласти "frustrating"?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Google перекладає дане слово як "що розстроюває". З мого власного досвіду, це не завжди те, що мається на увазі.

Для прикладу у реченні:

> This task is really frustrating

Чи є якийсь відповідник в українській мові?

Comment: *Це завдання - суцільне розчарування*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Як бачимо зі статті на [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozstrojuvaty):

   > Створювати поганий настрій, завдавати смутку.

   Це тільки п’яте зі значень слова *розстроювати* ([2 600 результатів в ґуґлі для *розстроїти*](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXqsbw79HSAhVBECwKHbTSAjwQPAgD#hl=uk&q=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%97%D1%82%D0%B8&*)).
2. Набагато питомішими в цьому випадку є слова:

   [Засмучувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/zasmuchuvaty) ([47 000 результатів в ґуґлі для *засмутити*](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH5Yb079HSAhVHWSwKHbZ8AvMQPAgD#hl=uk&q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&*))

   [Розчаровувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozcharovuvaty) ([460 000 результатів в ґуґлі для *розчарувати*](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib4fiN8NHSAhUBnywKHSwNCewQPAgD#hl=uk&q=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8&*))

   [Дратувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/dratuvaty) ([147 000 результатів в ґуґлі для *дратувати*](https://www.google.com.ua/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=nrzFWJiRKImu8wef4pbwDg&gws_rd=ssl#q=%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8&*))

   [Зневірятися](http://sum.in.ua/s/znevirjatysja) ([27 600 результатів в ґуґлі для *зневіритися*](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii8oPL89HSAhVFFiwKHUACCNsQPAgD#hl=uk&q=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F&*))

   Тоді кажемо:

   Той, що засмучує/розчаровує/дратує.

   Я зневірився через...
3. Не забуваймо, що в українській мові є слово [*фрустрація*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F).

   То ж маємо: той, що вводить у фрустрацію.
4. У вашому випадку все залежить від ситуації:

   Завдання може бути таким складним, що "в вас більше немає сил цим займатися", "вас це зводить з ґлузду", "вас втомило це завдання".